# Find the indicated angle, with one shape inset in a similar shape (window frame problem)

Tags: geometry

I have a something resembling a window frame (OK it IS a window frame). One edge is curved, given by the radius of 67.5842 units. The other two sides are straight lines meeting at a right angle... so what we have is basically a right triangle, with the hypotenuse curving outward. The base of the triangle is 2.35 units, and the height is 29.5.

Now inset into this triangle is a geometrically similar shape ... with a "frame width" of 3.625 units. Connecting the top-right corners (see diagram) of the two similar shapes is a line. I am interested in the angle between this line and the outside vertical edge. I know it is approximately 28 degrees. What I do not know is how to calculate it from the given information. In fact I am most interested in a formula for calculating this information given the above parameters (radius, height, width, frame width).

The angle of interest is between the two red segments in the diagram ... the frame width of 3.625 is not indicated in the diagram.

[image: Window frame with unknown angle]

Comment: If I can find the X and Y coordinates of the vertex of my angle here ... then I can finish it off. The coordinates I speak of are relative to the center of the circle forming the outer arc (which is also the center of the smaller inner circle). Once I have those, then I know the X coordinate of the "inner" top right corner ... and the radius of that arc, which Pythagoras could use to find the Y of the "inner" top right corner. Then I have the X,Y coordinates of both points and can find the slope of my line connecting them, which yields the angle.

Comment: I can't answer my own question (reputation) ... but I think it's 25.756570530795 ... my method is to find the center of the outer circle, assuming the lower-right corner is the coordinate origin... this is done using standard "two point + radius" circle methods ... then the smaller circle has same center, and smaller radius. I can finish it off from there. The problem is autocad says it is REALLY close to 28 degrees, so not sure what to think.